# How do I use NewsApi.org in my UWP Project?

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp

I'm using C# and UWP xml to create a news feed. Like a phone news widget but for the computer. I came across https://newsapi.org/ and thought it was interesting. But I don't know how to implement and there isn't any tutorials on C# for this api website. How do I use this and how do I show the article.Title, article.Author, and article.Description on 3 textblocks I created?

edit: I found a video for c# but it is for console.writeline, not a xaml front page.
So what I did was create a new class.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NewsAPI;
using NewsAPI.Models;
using NewsAPI.Constants;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace news
{
public class newsapi
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //public static async void Main(string[] args)
    //{

    //    newsapi program = new newsapi();
    //    await program.GetArticles();
    //}
    //public async Task GetArticles()
    //{
    //    string response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=06112b69bb054cfeb70bbf188873f98e");
    //    NewsResponse newsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsResponse>(response);
    //}

    public async static Task<Article> GetArticlesMain()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=06112b69bb054cfeb70bbf188873f98e");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Article));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (Article)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class NewsResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int totalResults { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Article
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    }
}
```

and tried to get the title of the news api in my mainpage.xaml in a textblock in a page_loaded event:

```
        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //RootObject myWeather = await OpenWeather.GetWeather(20, 30);
        Article article = await newsapi.GetArticlesMain();
        tbContent.Text = article.Title;

    }
```

But the textblock doesn't show anything and an exception user-unhandled was thrown in "tbContent.Text = article.Title" this line saying "Value cannot be null". So what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, The code you provided contains `ApiKey`, which is sensitive data, please delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the Json string from the network, if you want to convert to a type, you need to provide a class corresponding to the json structure.

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Article));
```

Here is the main problem, the obtained json string should be of type `NewsResponse`, so it should be like this:

```cs
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Article));
```

---

This is a complete process:

**News.cs**

```cs
public class NewsApi
{
    public async static Task<List<Article>> GetArticlesMain()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("your_news_url");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsResponse>(result);

        return data.articles;
    }
}

public class NewsResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public List<Article> articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public Source source { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string urlToImage { get; set; }
    public DateTime publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**News.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Article> articles = await NewsApi.GetArticlesMain();
    tbContent.Text = articles.First().title;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god what a genius! Thanks so much! May I know what exactly did you change? Also what is the [DataMember ] for? I saw it on a tutorial for OpenWeatherMap but why didn't it work here?